# Is Siddi CEP an blocking or non blocking engine?

Tags: wso2, siddhi

I have been doing some experimentation with siddhi CEP and found results that led me to believe that it is a blocking CEP meaning that it does not queue up events at a higher rate than it can process them.

Can someone tell me more about this?

Answer (score 2):

Siddhi by default does not buffer events. However, by using @Async annotation you can instruct siddhi to buffer events before processing, this will cause events arriving at a given event stream to get buffered before processing and a seperate thread will take the event from the buffer and process the events.

Please refer [siddhi architecture document](https://wso2.github.io/siddhi/documentation/siddhi-architecture/) for more information.

Comment: Let’s say you have a pattern  ‘every A-> B -> C’ . If I increase the arrival rate for all of the even streams what will engine do, will it create a parallel instance for every A. If yes, then to what extent?  The same question applies to time batch window of 20!seconds. if I increase arrival rate when the engine is processing that batch of 20 seconds, will it block the events that are arriving when that batch is complete and under processing as per expiration policy.

Comment: It will not automatically create parallel processing pipelines. Buffering of events will only happen if you use @Async against a stream.